# SimpleDb - Can i make a SELECT IN statement

Tags: amazon-simpledb

Can I make a simple "select in" statement using simpleDb

Ex: SELECT * FROM Domain WHERE id in (1,2,3)

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it. You can use IN syntax like this.

Comment: can i use subqueries?

Ex: SELECT * FROM Domain WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM OtherDomain)

Comment: Yes you can use subquery also.

Comment: SELECT * FROM tv_twilio_call_log WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tv_crm_studentdetails WHERE id IN (1,2,3));

Comment: This is my query and it's working fine, check your syntax are correct or not.

Comment: Down't work:
SELECT * FROM `conteudo-generico` WHERE Codigo IN (SELECT Codigo FROM `conteudo-generico` WHERE ItemName() = '3')

Comment: codigo should be an id